# How can I implement instagram-like navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and react navigation. I want to implement a navigator like instagram's navbar. My navbar has 4 Screens, each Screen has several child screens. The routing looks something like this

```
:    :    :    : 
A3   B3   C3   D3
|    |    |    |
A2   B2   C2   D2
|    |    |    |
A1   B1   C1   D1
|    |    |    |
A____B____C____D
```

#### Current Behavior

I tried nesting a stack navigator in a tab navigator but its not the behavior I want. When I press A B C D then back, the tab navigator takes me back to A instead of C.

I tried nesting a stack navigator in a Stack navigator, but its not the behavior I want. When I press A B C D then B the stack goes [A,B,C,D,B] instead of [A,C,D,B]

#### Expected Behavior

How do I implement a Custom navigation with these behaviors using react-navigation:

> A,B,C,D then back and it goes to C instead of A
>
> A,B,C,D then B and the stack goes [A,C,D,B] instead of [A,B,C,D,B]

Comment: Did you find a method to do this?